# Datatable - Having two values in one column

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm currently using the jquery plug in Datatables, to create a top 3 table per the car industry.

My first row, I have a title `Car Sales` Under that row I'd like to have 3 more columns that says:
`Highest Revenue, Second Highest Revenue, Third Highest Revenue` under each of this sections I am attempting to add two values per one column. For example, in my `Highest Revenue` column; I would like it  to have the title, and amount under the one column like `Walk ins 2002`.

I am unable to create this in Datatables as it creates a new column for every entry. Is there a way to link the two and have 2 sets of values under one column?

Here is an example of my expected outcome:

---

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|                 |                     |                        |                       |
| Car Industry    |   HIGHEST REVENUE   |  2ND HIGHEST REVENUE   |  3RD HIGHEST REVENUE  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 |                     |                        |                       |
|Car Sales        | Walk Ins 2002       | Appointments 764       |  Online 304           |
|                 |                     |                        |                       |
+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nwr9a4k/13/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datatables - Merge columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777075/datatables-merge-columns-together). In particular, look at the answer for DataTables version 1.10, which uses a `render` function to combine 2 values into one cell.

Comment: Additional information & examples for renderers can be found in the DataTables [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers).